# How to convert Dataset Column Bit Value in Boolean in CSHTML Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i know it seems very poor question but i want to convert bit value in boolean in CSHTML Page

for that i have written following code:

```
 <td style="width: 10%">
                    @if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Tables[0].Rows[0][5]))
                    {
                        <input id="Product + @i" name="rdbProduct" type="radio" value="@item.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]" checked="checked"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input id="Product + @i" name="rdbProduct" type="radio" value="@item.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]"/>
                    }
                </td>
```

Above code is written in loop and i want to check column value whether it is true or false and display radio button accordingly, but unfortunately all the radio buttons are displayed unchecked where there is true value in item.tables[0].rows[0][5] but still it does not go into true part of if condition.

Can anyone help me?

All answers are expected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [conditional attributes](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/201/Cleaner-Conditional-HTML-Attributes-In-Razor-Web-Pages)

```
<input id="Product + @i" name="rdbProduct" type="radio" value="@item.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]" checked="@item.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString().AsBool()"/>
```

If none of your checkboxes get checked, its because the item at `Tables[0].Rows[0][5]` evaluates to `false`. Perhaps you are missing an iterator? Should it in fact be `item.Tables[0].Rows[i][5]`?